# Law of large number in the proof of linearity of expectation

Tags: probability

One of the proofs for linearity of expectation is using simulation (Introduction to Probability, Dr. Blitzstein, p143). There are three columns containing simulated values of random variables, $X, Y$, and $X+Y$. It says that

1. Taking the arithmetic mean of all the numbers in the third column. By the law of large numbers, this is very close to $E(X+Y)$,
2. Taking the arithmetic mean of the first column and the arithmetic mean of the second column, then adding two column means. By the law of large numbers, this is very close to $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$.

I think the mean of the arithmetic means becomes close to $E(X+Y)$, not individual arithmetic mean. Could you let me know what I missed in understanding the law of large numbers?

Comment: i don't think simulation is the way to prove linearity of expectation.

Comment: i think the *sum* of individual means approaches the mean of the sum...

Comment: My question is not about the validity of the proof but about the statement that refers to the law of large numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The law of large numbers tells us that for a bunch of draws (each draw denoted $x_i$) from a distribution with mean $E(X)$, the arithmetic mean $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ of those draws approaches $E(X)$.

What the book is trying to demonstrate is that $E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$. To do this, it takes a bunch of draws from the random variable $X+Y$. The arithmetic mean of these is close to $E(X+Y)$ by the law of large numbers. It then takes a bunch of draws from $X$ and from $Y$ and estimates the mean by invoking the law of large numbers again.

Now we have estimates of $E(X),E(Y),E(X+Y)$ and indeed for these estimates the relationship $E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$ should be approximately true.

Comment: What I understand is that the average (expected value) of the arithmetic means approaches E(X). The individual arithmetic mean can be far away from the E(X).